# Why does Symfony API Platform ignore filters?

Tags: php, symfony, swagger, api-platform.com

I am working on a Symfony 5 + API Platform project. I am still fighting with API Filters. I made this work before setting up a fake API route from some controller. But, since there is an API Platform out of the box feature that allow this, I would like to "make" this work.

First of all, the entity filters are being ignored and API Platform is **aware** of that. According to **Symfony Profiler** > **API Platform** > **Resource Metadata**:

[image]

And according to **Data Providers** tab in the same page:

[image]

What I have tried so far is adding `@ApiFilter()` annotation to `Question` entity like [API documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/) explains:

```php
// ...
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=QuestionRepository::class)
 * @ApiResource(normalizationContext={"groups"={"question"}})
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"status": "partial"})
 */
class Question
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups("question")
     */
    private $status;
    
    // ...
}
```

I also have tried to specify the filter on the needed property to be filtered. (Thanks to *@EugeneRuban* from a previous question).

So that, why does API Platform ignores the filter?

#### Edit: This is what the Logs shows:

[image]

Comment: What does log say? Do you see `status` property at json when get `Question` item?

Comment: @shvv, The JSON contains all the properties, even the `status` one. I added the log to the question itself.

Comment: Very strange. If you create minimal reproducible example I can try to debug.

Comment: I am having SSL issues while trying to upload it to GitHub. But, not sure why... the filters there work just fine. I should instead upload my whole "troubled" project.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging for a while, it turned out that this was caused by a wrong use statement.

What works is:

```
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;
```

What does *not* work is:

```
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;
```

The strange thing is that the parameters do show up in Swagger with the last, wrong, use statement. But they don't actually work.